# Overriding UITabBarController , is it safe?

Tags: ios

Just wanted to know if overriding UITabBarController would get my app rejected? Is it allowed by Apple??

Any of you have submitted an app by overriding UITabBarController??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't get your app rejected.  In general it's fine to subclass UIKit classes, or any Cocoa Touch class.  Apple docs actually recommend subclassing for `UITableViewCell` if you can't get by just using its properties.  What gets you rejected is calling private APIs -- the ones that exist if you use reflection to inspect UIKit objects, but aren't in the reference material.

However, look closely at the delegate spec for what you're subclassing.  If you can use a partner object better, that's going to produce more reusable code.  In other words, when the SDK gets updated and the API class changes, your code is more likely to still work if you supply a delegate rather than subclassing.

Comment: You're welcome.  If you like my answer, would you mind clicking that green check to give me some points?  Welcome to Stack Overflow :)