# iOS6 Autorotation when switching back from support orientation to not supported orentation view

Tags: iphone, ios6

As every iOS developer is now a days sturggling with autorotationg features changed with `iOS6` launching with concerned to that i have one problem:

As my application supports `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait` but for few view controllers i want to support all   `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitAll` i implemented it as following :

**in my rootviewcontrller that is in my case navigation contrller :**

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return self.topViewController.shouldAutorotate; //you are asking your current controller what it should do
}
```

**in my viewcontrllers :**

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return //if view supports auto orientation then return yes else no
}
```

all is working well but 1 problem is...  suppose my 2nd view supports all orientations and 1st view only supports only portrait then if I rotate 2 view and get back if i my current view orientation(view2) is landscape then view1 will also not rotate to its supported orientation.

so how to overcome from this problem please if any then solutions are welcome.

Comment: How are you getting back to view1 from view2?

Comment: Take a look at these answers on SO already (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12504464/ios-6-uitabbarcontroller-supported-orientation-with-current-uinavigation-control) and/or this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12551247/autorotate-a-single-uiviewcontroller-in-ios-6-with-uitabbar)

Answer (score 0):

Try to reset your view orientation in `viewDidLoad` method. Solved it in my case.