# Programmatically UIViewController Autorotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I have a `UIViewController` with a XIB-file which contains a button. In the `IBAction` method of the button I create a new `UIViewController` with just one WebView.

```
UIViewController *onlineViewCtrl = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
[onlineViewCtrl.view addSubview:WebView];
```

I present this new ViewController:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:onlineViewCtrl animated:YES];
```

That works as expected but now on iOS versions <6 I have an issue with the autorotation of the screen.

The `onlineViewCtrl` does not rotate! Normally I would include the autorotate methods but how should I do that in case of the `onlineViewCtrl` where I don't have a own class or xib?

It is interesting that on iOS 6 everything works perfectly. Does anybody know why? But more important how does it work on iOS <6?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: refer [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12551247/autorotate-a-single-uiviewcontroller-in-ios-6-with-uitabbar) it may help you

Comment: Sorry that answer did not help. Again, basically the question is how do I implement the autorotate methods for my programmatically "onlineViewCtrl". In Java I would simply make an anonymous class...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found a solution: Categories
I have created my own category for a NavigationController and added the autorotate methods.