# it is possible to use UIImagePickerController in landscape mode in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

My application is in landscape mode and i want to open gallery and select video but i am getting error. is there any way to use UIImagePickerController in landscape mode or any other alternative way?

Comment: [Check This link For Landscape App](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12551247/autorotate-a-single-uiviewcontroller-in-ios-6-with-uitabbar)

& http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19374237/using-uiimagepickercontroller-in-landscape-orientation

Answer (score 0):

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

This should work. If your app only allows portrait. You have to do some extra work in the app delegate. You need to set a boolean property, call it restrictRotation. Then include AppDelegate.h in your class and set restrictRotation to true when you need to rotate it

```
-(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
{
if(self.restrictRotation)
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
else
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

Then in your class

```
- (void) orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)note
{
UIDevice * device = note.object;
switch(device.orientation)
{
    case UIDeviceOrientationPortrait:
        //do stuff
        break;
    case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
         //do stuff
        break;
    case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight:
       //do stuff
        break;
    default:
        break;
   };
}
-(void) restrictRotation:(BOOL) restriction
{
     AppDelegate* appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
appDelegate.restrictRotation = restriction;
}
```

That should help

Answer (score 0):

In your `ViewController.m`:

Make the SubClass(ViewController) of Image Picker Controller

```
@interface ViewController : UIImagePickerController

@end

@implementation ViewController

// Disable Landscape mode.

    - (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{

        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
    }
@end
```

Use the following code:

```
UIImagePickerController* picker = [[ViewController alloc] init];
        picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
        picker.delegate = self; 
 // etc.... do like Just as Default ImagePicker Controller
```

But make sure you check Portrait in deployment info,

because `UIImagePickerController` only supports Portrait mode.
 If you don't support portrait "globally" the image picker will crash as it has no usable orientations.